# RegEx in grep - bash picking up the string

Tags: bash

I'm trying to run this

```
grep -R -l --exclude-dir=merchant --exclude-dir=newport (\w*)\.execute\("ATTACH DATABASE '/include/location\.db' AS (\w*)"\);  * | wc -l
```

but I keep getting this error

```
-sh: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

I've tried escaping all the brackets like this:

```
grep -R -l --exclude-dir=merchant --exclude-dir=newport '"\(\w*\)\.execute\("ATTACH DATABASE \'/include/location\.db\' AS \(\w*\)"\);'  *.esp
```

But when I hit enter, it then goes to this:

```
>
```

Indicating that I have an open quote. Can anyone assist here?

Thanks

Comment: You have a stray `"` in your second example.

Answer (score 1):

How about quoting that whole thing and escaping the internal quotes:

```
grep -R -l --exclude-dir=merchant --exclude-dir=newport "(\w*)\.execute\(\"ATTACH DATABASE '/include/location\.db' AS (\w*)\"\);"  * | wc -l
```

Comment: Oops, a semicolon got loose.  Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

How about this one -

```
grep -R -l --exclude-dir=merchant --exclude-dir=newport '(\w*)\.execute\("ATTACH DATABASE '/include/location\.db' AS (\w*)"\);'  * | wc -l
```

Comment: i think you're quotes have gone awry